# UITableViewCell is checked randomly when i scroll up and down

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5

My code representing my approach works great, however, when i scroll down and up, i got some UItableViewCells checked in all my sections.
Can you please help me figure out what wrong with my logic.
This is my whole code:

**The Definition file .h:**

```
@interface RechercheThematiqueViewController : UIViewController{

    NSDictionary *tableContents;
    NSArray *sortedKeys;


}
//added
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSMutableArray *tableData;
//
-(IBAction)goBackToFirstView:(id)sender;
@end
```

**The implementation file .m:**

```
static NSString * const kCellTextKey = @"CellTextKey";
static NSString * const kCellStateKey = @"CellStateKey";
//
#import "RechercheThematiqueViewController.h"
@implementation RechercheThematiqueViewController

@synthesize tableData;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 

    NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc]
                         initWithObjects:@"Mairie",@"Préfectures et sous-préfectures",@"Palais de justice",@"Commissariat de police",@"Gendarmerie",@"Caisse primaire d'assurance maladie",@"Banque",@"Centre commercial et grand magasin",@"Supermarché et hypermarché",@"Agence immobilière",@"Location d'appartement",@"Notaire",@"Discothèques",@"Casino",@"théâtre et concert",@"cinéma",@"musée",@"Bibliothèque et médiathèque",@"parc d'attraction",@"Zoo/parc animalier",@"Club de forme",@"Association et club de sport",@"Stade et complexe sportif",@"Golf",@"Tennis",@"Equitation",@"Garage auto / moto",@"Auto-école",@"Stations services",@"Hôtel",@"Camping",@"Location saisonnière",@"Village et club de vacances",@"Restaurant",@"pizzeria",@"traiteur",@"Bar",@"Restauration rapide",@"Service d'urgence",@"Médecin généraliste",@"Kiné",@"Dentiste",@"Clinique",@"Maternité",@"Pharmacies",@"Vétérinaire",@"office de tourisme",@"Visite de Sites et circuits touristiques",@"Agence de voyages",nil];
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[tempArray count]];

    for(NSString * myStr in tempArray) {
        NSNumber *state = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
        NSLog(@"%@",myStr);
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myStr, kCellTextKey, state, kCellStateKey, nil];
        [arr addObject:dict];
    }

    tableData = [arr mutableCopy];

        //

    //charger le TableView
    //section1
    NSArray *arrTemp1 = [[NSArray alloc]
                         initWithObjects:@"Mairie",@"Préfectures et sous-préfectures",@"Palais de justice",@"Commissariat de police",@"Gendarmerie",@"Caisse primaire d'assurance maladie",nil];
    //section2
    NSArray *arrTemp2 = [[NSArray alloc]
                         initWithObjects:@"Banque",@"Centre commercial et grand magasin",@"Supermarché et hypermarché",nil];
    //section3
    NSArray *arrTemp3 = [[NSArray alloc]
                         initWithObjects:@"Agence immobilière",@"Location d'appartement",@"Notaire",nil];
    //section4
    NSArray *arrTemp4 = [[NSArray alloc]
                         initWithObjects:@"Discothèques",@"Casino",@"théâtre et concert",@"cinéma",@"musée",@"Bibliothèque et médiathèque",@"parc d'attraction",@"Zoo/parc animalier",nil];
    //section5
    NSArray *arrTemp5 = [[NSArray alloc]
                         initWithObjects:@"Club de forme",@"Association et club de sport",@"Stade et complexe sportif",@"Golf",@"Tennis",@"Equitation",nil];

    //section6
    NSArray *arrTemp6 = [[NSArray alloc]
                         initWithObjects:@"Garage auto / moto",@"Auto-école",@"Stations services",nil];
    //section7
    NSArray *arrTemp7 = [[NSArray alloc]
                         initWithObjects:@"Hôtel",@"Camping",@"Location saisonnière",@"Village et club de vacances",nil];
    //section8
    NSArray *arrTemp8 = [[NSArray alloc]
                         initWithObjects:@"Restaurant",@"pizzeria",@"traiteur",@"Bar",@"Restauration rapide",nil];
    //section9
    NSArray *arrTemp9 = [[NSArray alloc]
                         initWithObjects:@"Service d'urgence",@"Médecin généraliste",@"Kiné",@"Dentiste",@"Clinique",@"Maternité",@"Pharmacies",@"Vétérinaire",nil];
    //section10
    NSArray *arrTemp10 = [[NSArray alloc]
                         initWithObjects:@"office de tourisme",@"Visite de Sites et circuits touristiques",@"Agence de voyages",nil];
    NSDictionary *temp =[[NSDictionary alloc]
                         initWithObjectsAndKeys:arrTemp1,@"Administrations Enseignement",arrTemp2,
                     @"Commerces Banques",arrTemp3,@"Immobilier",arrTemp4,@"Divertissement Culture",arrTemp5,@"Sports Loisirs",arrTemp6,@"Auto - moto",arrTemp7,@"Hébergement",arrTemp8,@"Restauration",arrTemp9,@"Santé",arrTemp10,@"Tourisme",nil];

    self->tableContents =temp;
    self->sortedKeys =[[self->tableContents allKeys]
                       sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return [self->sortedKeys count];

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView

titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    return [self->sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section];

}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table

 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSArray *listData =[self->tableContents objectForKey:
                        [self->sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section]];
    return [listData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView

         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CheckedTableViewCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

NSDictionary *rowData = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [rowData objectForKey:kCellTextKey];

if ([[rowData objectForKey:kCellStateKey] boolValue]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    BOOL newState = ![[dict objectForKey:kCellStateKey] boolValue];
    NSDictionary *newDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dict objectForKey:kCellTextKey], kCellTextKey, [NSNumber numberWithBool:newState], kCellStateKey, nil];
    [self.tableData replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:newDict];

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}

@end
```

Comment: does the error also occur if you only scroll and don't select a row ?

Comment: It seems that everything is Ok with your code

Comment: Reload your tableview after scroll.

Comment: i have already reload it: `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}`

Comment: @Aadhira: I have edited my post to show you the entire code of my class, everything works great (checking, unchecking), the only wrong thing is that some UITableViewCell keeper changing (checked) when i scroll my table.

Answer (score 0):

your cell isnt autoreleased:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

maybe this is the error?

and you should deselect your Cell in the:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
...
...

}
```

Comment: I use the ARC in my project, for the second note, it doesn't change anything, the `UItableViewCell` of other sections keeped changing their check status :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a logical mistake in your code. But it is up to you to decide how you require that.

Anyhow, it seems that for each section, you want the contents from arrTemp1,arrTemp2,arrTemp3.. for each section. But as per your code, it is showing the elements from `tableData` and so the elements are same for each section. Only thing, since you are getting the count for each section from `tableContents` dictionary, the count varies.

So you might need to look at the logic in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` whether you have to show the contents from `tableData` or `tableContents`. If you use `tableData`, the elements are same and so, if you check in one section, it will be reflected in all sections.